# Has vs had (past tense)

Tags: prepositions

Which one is grammatically correct?

> It was not until grade 2 when I discovered the 'earth' has a name.

Or

> It was not until grade 2 when I discovered the 'earth' had a name.

Comment: Although not wrong, the use of *when* sound strange to me here. I would more naturally say *that*.

Answer (score 10):

Either. Normally we back=shift, so with a past-tense matrix verb ('discovered') we use a past-tense verb in the embedded clause.

But when the embedded clause denotes a state which continues to the present, we can use the present instead.

To my ear, the past sounds more natural: if you use the present, you are emphasising that the state still exists.

Comment: Agreed, for example: "I discovered in Grade 2 that men had never visited the moon": what you discovered then was true at the time, but is no longer true today, so "had" is needed.